# Setting the digits after decimal point

Tags: c

So with *float* when I enter some number it prints with 6 decimal digits. I know I can adjust number of digits with something like "*%.2f*" (then number has only two). But my question is; is there any command that prints exact number of digits that are inputed.

Example if I input number **2.5**

With only printf ("%f", number); it will print **2.500000**

Or with printf ("%.2f", number); it will print **2.50**

So is there any way that it could print **2.5** (with one decimal point) and in the same time if I input number like *2.51* it will print that number with 2 decimal points (**2.51**)

Comment: There's no straightforward way, no.  The variable has no way of remembering how the user typed the number in.

Comment: Whenever you're reading a value treat it as string, convert it to double/float into separate variable and use  whichever is appropriate when neeeded.

Comment: As a binary floating point number 2.5 and 2.50 will look exactly the same.

Comment: `2.51` cannot be exactly represented using floating point

Comment: So, if the user types `2.5`, you want to print `2.5`, but if the user types `2.50`, you want to print `2.50`, and if they type `2.50000`, that's what you want to print? If you analyze the string, you'll be able to do it.  If you don't, you won't — because the in-memory representation of the converted values is the same and there's no way to tell which of those was used. What do you plan to do about the recalcitrant user who types 0.00025E+4 or 25000E-4? What is the correct output for these? Note that the `%lf` format accepts the exponential form just as happily as it does the fixed-point form.

Comment: Also, have you looked at `%g`?  It suppresses trailing zeroes.

Comment: The only problem with %g is that you are specifying a maximum precision, which results in rounding.. If he ever moves to BigNum or something that could present some issues for him.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  To do so, you would have to write some code to determine how many places after the decimal point you need to print.

I'll leave converting the pseudo-code below to actual code to you:

```
 value = 2.51
 places = 1
 while(testDigitsAfterDecimal(value, places) { places ++ }
 sprintf(format_string, "%%.%df", places)
 printf(format_string, value)
```

In summary, if you write code to mathematically test for places following the decimal and keep count of how many places you need, you can then use that number in a `sprintf` to create a format string that specifies the desired number of places.  With that done, you can pass that string to `printf` as the format to print your number.